# ACPI vs Gnome-Power-Manager

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, acpi

I ran acpi on the terminal and it said 20 mins before the battery is fully charged. But gnome-poower-manager applet says 40mins. Which one is a better estimate?

Answer (score 2):

g-p-m gets its information from hal which in turn gets its information from ACPI, so you may see some delay before the data filters through to g-p-m.